# Verilog: Reg is not declared

Tags: verilog, hdl

Here is the declaration of the reg assignment

```
reg [5:0]R = {bi7 ,[15:11]RGB}; //bi7 is a parameter
```

but at the last line of the module i get this error where it points at the same reg assignment.

```
ERROR:HDLCompiler:69 - "path.v" Line 58: <R> is not declared.
```

Can anyone help me with this , cause my whole experience with verilog is just a book :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In verilog, you can only assign a value to a `reg` in `always` or `initial` blocks. You've also got the bit range for stripping bits from you `RGB` bus on the wrong side of the bus name.

```
reg [5:0] r;
always @(RGB) begin
    r = {bi7, RGB[15:11]};
end
```

Note that in verilog, parameter names such as `bi7` in your code, are usually defined and written in UPPER CASE to make them easy to pick out.